# IN not returning the desired solution?

Tags: mysql

So basically I have 2 tables one is customer and the other one is department both of them have a common attribute, 'branch'.

I was trying to fetch the department_manager(from department table)
and customer_name(from customer table)

So my query was

```
     SELECT department_manager,customername FROM customer,department WHERE 
 customer.branch=department.branch;
```

This gives me the desired solution.

But then I thought of getting the same result using a subquery

```
    SELECT department_manager,customername FROM customer,department      WHERE 
 customer.branch IN ( select branch from department);
```

This is not giving me the desired solution as the first one was giving me. I basically want to join the two tables if they involve the common attribute ie the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply wrong.  In your second query, you have two references to `department`.  They are independent.

The right way to write the query is using an explicit `JOIN`:

```
SELECT d.department_manager, c.customername
FROM customer c JOIN
     department d
     ON c.branch = d.branch;
```

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I actually saw a tutorial in which it said you have to use commas (if more than 1 table) in the FROM clause!

Comment: @user6177394 . . . Well, the tutorial is only out of date by about 25 years.  Get better teaching materials.

Comment: Well I saw one on this
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm
and there are many more.

Would you like to suggest your preference?

Comment: @pluto20010 . . . It is not a preference.  You can google about how to do joins and see many discussions on the issue.  The standard is `JOIN` (and related keywords).  They are more powerful.  Commas are supported for back compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you are particular in using a subquery..

```
SELECT department_manager,customername 
FROM customer 
Inner Join department 
On customer.branch=department.branch  
WHERE customer.branch IN ( select branch from department);
```

Comment: I am getting the desired solution without using the WHERE clause ie the last line in your code.

So there is no use of that subquery?

Comment: @pluto20010 Yes thats right., you will get it simply using a join condition no need of that subquery.

Comment: Yes,  so what if I wanted to extract the result using just a subquery.  What would have the code been?

Comment: @pluto20010 Then I think you can return only column from one table at a time. 
Select department_manager From department Where department.branch in (Select branch from customer)

Similarly 

Select customername from Customer where customer.branch in (Select branch from department)